# Problem working with chips programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin, android-chips

I'm adding chips into chipGropup programatically like this

XML

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
                android:id="@+id/chipGroup"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:singleSelection="true"
                app:selectionRequired="true"
                app:singleLine="true">

            </com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
```

This is the function to add chips and contains the listener

```
fun addChips(Names: List<String>){
    Names.forEach {
        val chip = Chip(requireContext())
        val drawable = ChipDrawable.createFromAttributes(requireContext(), null, 0, R.style.Widget_MaterialComponents_Chip_Choice)
        chip.setChipDrawable(drawable)
        chip.text = it
        chip.isClickable = true
        chip.isCheckable = true
        binding.chipGroup.isSingleSelection = true
        chip.id = ViewCompat.generateViewId()

        binding.chipGroup.addView(chip)
    }

    binding.chipGroup.forEach { child ->
        (child as? Chip)?.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, _ ->
            makeAction()
        }
    }
}


fun makeAction(){
    //val id = binding.chipGroup.checkedChipId //NOT WORKING
    val ids = binding.chipGroup.checkedChipIds
    val categoryNames = mutableListOf<String>()
    ids.forEach { id ->
        categoryNames.add(binding.chipGroup.findViewById<Chip>(id).text.toString())
    }
    viewModel.chipFilter(categoryNames, args.orderToEdit.product.sections.toMutableList())
}
```

I have two problems.
One is that I can’t use checkedChipId because returns -1, so i need to use checkedChipIds. The strange thing is that I define chipgroup and chips as singleSelection.
The other problem is when I click one chip, entered two times to the setOnCheckedChangeListener

Secondly, is there any way to start the fragment with the first chip selected?
Thanks for all!

Comment: What is your exact requirement here? Do you want to call viewModel.chipFilter whenever checked state of any of the chips changes and pass the text of the selected chip to viewModel?

Comment: i had a same problem. Try getting chips by tag, not by id.

Comment: Yes, when I click on some chip I want to call viewModel.chipFilter, and display some text on the screen depending on what chip I clicked, so I pass the clicked chip name to chipFilte